# MVVM for SfChat Control in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Does the `SfChat` control for Xamarin Forms require specific properties for `Messages`?

In my model, I do have the `ObservableCollection<MessageModel> messages` property to handle messages but the properties of my `MessageModel` are different than what's in the [getting started documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/chat/getting-started). Do they need to match e.g. `Author`, `Text`, etc? For example, in my model, the property is not named `Author` but `Sender`. Another one is `Text` property. In my model it's named `Body`.

Currently when I run the code, I'm getting the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

I do recognize this error which is thrown if I don't bind properties of my model to the control correctly. Any suggestions as to how to properly bind properties of my model to the control or do I need to make sure property names are exactly what the control expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/chat/data-binding) seem to cover this

> The IChatMessageConverter interface provides the methods
> ConvertToChatMessage and ConvertToData to convert an item of an
> existing collection to a chat message and to convert a chat message to
> an item of the existing data collection respectively.

you need to provide a `IChatMessageConverter` that will convert your class to and from the SF data format